# "Люблю, и все тут!" Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Увидела на бигборде такую надпись:

> Люблю(,) и все тут!

Только никаких знаков препинания там нет. А я бы поставила запятую после "люблю". Как все-таки правильно и почему?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Люблю - и все тут! Ставится тире, ведь вторая часть предложения является итогом, выводом первого.